# Is the transaction fee reduced from the transaction value?

Tags: transactions, fees, gas-price

Address `A` holds 1 ether and address `B` holds 0 ethers.

Lets create a transaction to transfer all balance from `A` to `B`.

This transaction will consume roughly `gas_price * gas_used = 20 gwei * 21000 = 0.00042 ethers` at the time of writing.

In the end, the `B` will hold `1 - 0.00042 = 0.99958 ethers` either way since there's only 1 ether in total existence.

When the sender creates the transaction, say with https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendtransaction, should he leave the estimated transaction cost `0.00042 ethers` in `A` and reduce the transaction value to `0.99958`? Or is the fee reduced from the transaction's value automatically?

Put another way, if the sender sets the transaction's value to be 1 ether, will this transaction complete or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not amend the value to be transferred by costs. The value specified in the transaction is transferred as is.

On top that, the sender will be charged `gasSpent * gasPrice`, which in the case of value transfer is fixed (as mentioned in the question).  This is taken additionally.

Note that the `geth` node will check if the account balance is less than `gasLimit * gasPrice` + `value` and reject the transaction if it is.